# Is it possible to get the promise of an async function from inside the function itself?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Say I have

```
function my_func() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
        resolve(5);
    });
    some_global = promise;
    return promise;
}
```

I get the promise being returned by my_func and also assign it to a global variable. Is it possible to also do this while using the async syntax? Sorta like

```
async function my_func() {
    some_global = ???
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to put it into a global variable, but I think I've needed this too before

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve by assigning an intermediate Promisified value from an async function to a global variable *within* the function? Why not just `some_global = my_func()` or probably something that doesn't rely on syncing up code via globals?

Comment: @VLAZ there is no logical problem I'm trying to solve, its about readability in this type of situation. I think everyone would agree that the async keyword is infinitely nicer than nesting function bodies and if I could use it in this situation it would be even nicer.

Comment: @user81993 I'd say you *shouldn't have* this kind of situation. You shouldn't be assigning promises to a global variable. Even if you absolutely have to (which, I'd imagine, would be bad design that is being patched up rather than properly fixed), then what's the problem with just calling the async function and assigning the result to the global? Why do you have to do it *from inside the body* instead?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set the promise to your global variable and get the response of that promise when you call the function with the async/await pattern i think it would be like this

```
async function my_func() {
  some_global = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(5);
    reject('error');
  })

  return await some_global;
}

async function func_call() {
  console.log(await my_func());
}

func_call()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably as follows:

```
function my_func() {
  let promise = (async () => {
    return 5;
  });

  some_global = promise;
  return promise;
}
```

Comment: That's what OP already had. The question is how to do the equivalent from within an `async function`.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, OP can now put `return 5` or whatever in the nested async function. But this must be wrapped in a regular function to obtain the promise.